# How to select all rows which have same value in some column

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am new to sql so please be kind.

Assume i must display all the employee_ids which have the same phone number(Both columns are in the same table)

How am i to proceed on this problem inner join or something.

Comment: Please provide simple data and the desired result based on it.

Answer (score 45):

```
SELECT * FROM employees e1, employees e2 
WHERE e1.phoneNumber = e2.phoneNumber 
AND e1.id != e2.id;
```

**Update** : for better performance and faster query its good to add `e1` before *

```
SELECT e1.* FROM employees e1, employees e2 
WHERE e1.phoneNumber = e2.phoneNumber 
AND e1.id != e2.id;
```

Answer (score 37):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE PhoneNumber IN (
    SELECT PhoneNumber
    FROM Employees
    GROUP BY PhoneNumber
    HAVING COUNT(Employee_ID) > 1
    )
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07e65/2)

Comment: How to use this query for text field in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY phone_number) as Phone_CT
      FROM YourTable
      )sub
WHERE Phone_CT > 1
ORDER BY phone_number, employee_ids
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3625e/3/0)

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
from Table1 as t1
where
    exists (
        select *
        from Table1 as t2 
        where t2.Phone = t1.Phone and t2.id <> t1.id
    )
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f277a/1)</kbd>**